# Mocking a method that doesnt return a value

Tags: c#, mocking

I have a method which contains a series of calls to a method which checks if string input is null or empty. If its empty, it sets the 2nd parameter to false;

```
public bool inputsContainData()
{
    bool validInputs = True;

    _helper.StringContainsData(_view.FilePath1, validInputs);
    _helper.StringContainsData(_view.FilePath2, validInputs);

    //...

    Return validInputs;
}
```

The StringContainsData() method is in a class which is DI'd into the presenter. The method doesnt return anything since the result variable is of reference type.

```
public void StringContainsData(string input, bool result)
{
    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        result = false;
    }
}
```

Im having some issues with this because i cant mock the StringContainsData() and have it return a specific result. The only solution i can think of is if i include a second If statement as follows:

```
    public bool StringContainsData(string input, bool result)
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            if(result != false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(result == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thus stopping me from having True,False,True => final result = true rather than false.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your method is useless. The change to `result` inside `StringContainsData` can't be seen by the outside method because the parameter is not a `ref` or `out` parameter.

Comment: Fix `StringContainsData` before even going to mocking... Also, why mock such a trivial function?

Comment: Again, please fix your code. It wont even compile.

Comment: @leppie, sorry id written it in without checking in VS. Ive updated it as u have asked. It should be ok now (touch wood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to restructure to chain the calls.

There is no need for another if, simply ANDing the previous answer with the new one will work.

```
public bool StringContainsData(string aString, bool answerToDate) {
    return answerToDate && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aString);
}

public bool inputsContainData() {        
    bool validInputs = True;        

    validInputs = _helper.StringContainsData(_view.FilePath1, validInputs);        
    validInputs = _helper.StringContainsData(_view.FilePath2, validInputs);        

    return validInputs;        
}
```

or if you want to have some fun

```
public bool inputsContainData() {        
    var inputs = new []{ _view.FilePath1, _view.FilePath2};
    return inputs.Aggregate(true, (ret, inp) => ret && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inp));        
}
```

*Notes:*

The last version looks like complication for its own sake but if you are going to add more file paths to check extending the array is simpler/safer than cut/past on the assignment/call lines.

In the function, check **ret** first using the short circuit (&&) means that we do not need to check the current input if we have already failed.

Comment: You are correct. I have gone with a slightly different approach at present (using a property and have the logic in there since the InputsContainData() doesnt just contain StringContainsData() methods.)  One of my tests is still not working though so i might resort to ur solution in the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=vs.71%29) which means that the value will be passed to the method and not a referenc .

You have two options, you can either return a `bool` result from the method `StringContainsData` like this:

```
public bool StringContainsData(string input, bool result)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
}
```

Or you can use `ref`/`out` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Hans Rudel The code as written will not take account of the previous results. If the first FilePath is null but the second is not using then this will give a true result even though the intent seems to be to ensure that none of the paths are blank.

Comment: AlanT's ans is more appropriate to the original question so i have switched the answer to his. Still +1 on ur answer though + thanks for your help.